# C++Builder: "highlight brace pair" option mess text selection

Tags: c++builder

C++Builder: Community Edition

In **Options** → **Editor** there is **Highlight brace pair** tick.

I really like this feature. But it makes hell to select something. Eg I got:

```
msg(p, "You cannot create or extend houses near other house doors.");
```

If I'm trying to select this text:
*You cannot create or extend houses near other house doors.*

It selects also quotes:
*"You cannot create or extend houses near other house doors."*

But I don't need to select quotes! No matter how I try to select it - with mouse or keyboard - it adds to selection quotes.. If I disable "Highlight brace pair" option - it works as it should.

Please help - is there some way to have this option and normal selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darn, I got it.

To select text without quotes you need to select it from right to left. So if you select text from left to right - it includes quotes. If from right to left - nope :)